# How to get file path of PDF file in android 11+ in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to show PDF pages in Image composable within LazyColumn using bitmap.
Code in Mainactivity.kt, below code is for File Picker

```
val createFileLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) { uri: Uri? ->
    uri?.let {
        viewmodel.convertDocumentsToBitmap(context, uri)
    }
}
FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                            // For Android 13 and above
                            createFileLauncher.launch(arrayOf("application/pdf"))
                        } else {
                            // For Android 12 and below, use the old READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
                            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                requestPermission.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            } else {
                                createFileLauncher.launch(arrayOf("application/pdf"))
                            }
                        }

                    }, modifier = modifier
                        .constrainAs(fab_refreshFiles) {
                            end.linkTo(parent.end)
                            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                        }
                        .offset(-24.dp, -24.dp)) {
                        Text(text = "Add")
                    }
```

Below code is from Viewmodel_Main.kt,

```
 var pageCount = mutableStateOf(0)
val bitmaps = mutableListOf<Bitmap>()
fun convertDocumentsToBitmap(context: Context, uri: Uri?){
    if (uri != null){
        try {
            // Open a PDF file with PdfRenderer
            val file = uri.toFile()
            val fileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)
            val pdfRenderer = PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor)
            // Get a page from the PDF (0 is the first page)
            // Create a bitmap for each page and add it to the list
            for (pageIndex in 0 until pdfRenderer.pageCount) {
                val page: PdfRenderer.Page = pdfRenderer.openPage(pageIndex)
                val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(page.width, page.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
                page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY)
                bitmaps.add(bitmap)
                page.close()
            }
            pageCount.value = pdfRenderer.pageCount
            pdfRenderer.close()
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error ($e): Rendering PDF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "File path not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

This code of convertDocumentsToBitmap() was given by ChatGPT-4 on bing. Now i am frustrated debugging it.

I had also used `val file = uri.path?.let { File(it) }` instead of `val file = uri.toFile()` but it gave FileNotFoundException

Comment: `This code of convertDocumentsToBitmap() was given by ChatGPT-4 on bing.`

Comment: Rather than use ChatGPT, perhaps you should be using one of the existing Compose UI libraries for PDF rendering. See [this](https://github.com/GRizzi91/bouquet) and [this](https://github.com/pratikksahu/JetPDFVue), for example. See also [this Medium post](https://medium.com/telepass-digital/how-to-show-a-pdf-with-jetpack-compose-74fc773adbd0) for some notes on memory management.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the **PdfRenderer** class to convert PDF pages to bitmaps. It appears that **you are experiencing issues with the convertDocumentsToBitmap function**.

It's important to note that the OpenDocument API in Android 11+ is used for selecting and opening documents, and it provides a Uri to the selected document. However, **the uri.toFile() method does not exist in the Android SDK**. To work with a PDF file, you need to access it using the content resolver.

Here's a modified version of your code that properly opens and renders PDF pages using PdfRenderer:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.asImageBitmap
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val bitmaps = mutableListOf<Bitmap>()

    fun convertDocumentToBitmap(context: Context, uri: Uri) {
        try {
            val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
            val pdfRenderer = PdfRenderer(contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")!!)

            bitmaps.clear()

            for (pageIndex in 0 until pdfRenderer.pageCount) {
                val page = pdfRenderer.openPage(pageIndex)
                val width = 1024 // Set your preferred width here
                val height = (width * page.height / page.width)
                val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
                page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY)
                bitmaps.add(bitmap)
                page.close()
            }

            pdfRenderer.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error ($e): Rendering PDF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun PDFPageRenderer(viewModel: MainViewModel) {
    val bitmaps = viewModel.bitmaps
    if (bitmaps.isNotEmpty()) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            for (bitmap in bitmaps) {
                Image(
                    bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap(),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp) // Adjust the size as needed
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen(viewModel: MainViewModel) {
    val createFileLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) { uri: Uri? ->
        uri?.let {
            viewModel.convertDocumentToBitmap(context, it)
        }
    }

    Column {
        FloatingActionButton(
            onClick = {
                createFileLauncher.launch(arrayOf("application/pdf"))
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Add PDF")
        }

        PDFPageRenderer(viewModel)
    }
}

// In your MainActivity or wherever you set up your Composable
val viewModel = MainViewModel()
MainScreen(viewModel)
```

In this modified code, I made several changes:

1. Removed the unnecessary if **(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)** condition as the OpenDocument API is available for Android 11 and above.
2. Properly opened and rendered the PDF using PdfRenderer by acquiring a file descriptor from the content resolver.
3. Cleared the bitmaps list before rendering the pages.
4. Displayed the rendered bitmaps in a Composable.

Make sure to adjust the width and height of the rendered bitmaps and other UI elements to fit your requirements.

Comment: Have no idea why this answer is downvoted. It tells clearly not to change an Uri to a File. And you get a descriptor using content resolver on the uri. Thats it. In Java: `ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");` Its a pitty that a different approach to generate the Bitmap is given. That was not asked for.

Comment: You forgot: No permissions are needed to use OpenDocument().

Comment: @blackapps Your both comments contradicted, you mean answer I shared above is wrong or need to improve. And regarding second comment I already mention we below need to remove permission